# How to identify user tapped on Editor field in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, editor, scrollview, contentoffset

First thing, I have an Editor.I can Identify if the user entered any text in that Edior.But i need to return something when the user tapped on the Editor. How to achieve this?

```
        var msgEditor = new Editor
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
            HeightRequest = App.ScreenHeight,
        };
```

Secong thing, Editor is inside the scrollview.When i tapped on the Editor scrollview scrolls down.I need to manually pull down to see the cursor.How to set content offset when i tapped on Editor?

```
  ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView

  {
      Content = msgEditor,
  };
  Content = scroll;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the editor, you have the focus event that notifies you that the user tapped the editor. You can do as follow :

```
{
    var editor = new Editor();
    editor.Focused += EditorOnFocused;
}

private void EditorOnFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs focusEventArgs)
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When i tapped on the editor scrollview goes to the end. Is it possible to set content offset in Xamarin?